# Javascript condition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with my script js, in fact, I use jQuery for sending data with ajax to a PHP file. I expected a dataType text in return for which I want to test with Javascript.

My goal is that if the text returned from PHP is equal to "inserted", I want to redirect the user another web page, or else a pop-up will appear with the error message returned from PHP.

But the problem is that even if the response from PHP was "inserted", it does not redirect the user to the expected page but it shows a pop-up with "inserted" as message.

This is the ajax source code :

```
$('#valider').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $('#form-filter').get(0);
  var formData = new FormData(form); // get the form data
  // on envoi formData vers mail.php
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
    url: 'insert-prescripteur.php', // the url where we want to POST
    data: formData, // our data object
    dataType: 'text', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(server_response) {
      if (server_response === "inserted") {
        window.location.href = "page.php";
      } else {
        $('#erreur_inscription').html('<p>' + server_response + '</p>');
        $('#triggerwarning').trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#ferme').trigger('click');
        }, 4000);
      }
    }, // --> this was missing
    error: function(server_response) {
      alert(server_response);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is it `success` or `inserted`? You have `if(server_response==="inserted"){}` if it is success like you state then that will always fail.

Comment: please write the content of "server_response"

Comment: Sorry, it was "succes" before but i have wondered that it was the problem so I have changed it to "inserted" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please still include your output here (_for `server_response`_), so we can answer the question correctly.

Comment: @Troyer Yes, rigth after the insertion of data in the database i made an echo("inserted")

Comment: The output of the server_response var is "inserted"

Comment: I have tried to do an alert(server_response) and console.log(server_response) and it shows "inserted" if PHP has inserted the data in the database, but it doesn't redirect the page but shows me a pop-up with "inserted" as error.

Comment: The condition must be (server_response=="inserted") (NOT ===)

Comment: You're missing a `}` for the success block it looks like.

Comment: thanks! i have corrected it, but now it goes directly to the php page if it doesn't pass to the e.preventDefault();

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand?

Comment: @nerdlyist 
I have already closed the brace but now it acts as if I directly passed my data to the php file without going through ajax so by submitting the form, this redirects me to the php file that performs the action and that does display the message "inserted" instead of redirecting me to "page.php"

Comment: Is `('#valider')` the forms submit button?

Comment: @nerdlyist yes of course!

Comment: I cannot appear to reproduce your issue with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you all for your answers. I found the solution to my problem, it is not due to javascript but to the text returned by PHP, instead of "inserted" PHP returned "inserted" with two blan spaces after, then I just changed the javascript condition like this:

```
if(server_response === "inserted  ")
```

Or a replace would be better, but both works well :

```
server_response = server_response.replace('  ', '');

    if(server_response === "inserted")
    {
       window.location.replace("page.php");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

replace server_response==="inserted" to server_response == "inserted"

Comment: How does that change anything? If the server sends "inserted" back as plain text, it will be identical to the string "inserted".